# Configuring a Pivot Table with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My VBA code creates a Pivot-Table but doesn't configure it.
Here the code to create the Pivot_table:

```
WSAP.Cells(2, 5) = APIndexRow + 1
WSAP.Cells(3, 5) = APColumn
Set PivotSICRange = Range(WSAP.Cells(1, 2), WSAP.Cells((APIndexRow 
   + 1), (APColumn - 2)))
Set PivotSICCache = 
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
   SourceData:=PivotSICRange)          'Set the Pivot Cache
Set PivotSIC = 
PivotSICCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WSAP.Cells(1, 10), 
  TableName:="SIC Code Pivot") 'Create the Pivot Table based on the 
  Pivot Cache

If (CountryFound) Then
    With PivotSIC
       .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 3).Value).Orientation = 
        xlRowField
       .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 2).Value).Orientation = 
        xlPageField
       .AddDataField .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value), "Total " 
        & WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value, xlSum
       .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 3).Value).AutoSort xlDescending, 
        "Total " & WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value
    End With
Else
    With PivotSIC
      .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 2).Value).Orientation = 
       xlPageField
      .AddDataField .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value), "Total " 
       & WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value, xlSum
      .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 3).Value).AutoSort xlDescending, 
       "Total " & WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value
    End With
End If
```

APIndexRow+1 is 62 (last row of the table)
APColumn-2 is 4 (columns D that is the last column of the table)
It creates the Pivot-Table in the right place and associates the right parameters. This means that I see the Pivot_Table, if I select it, I see the fields (in columns B, C and D, as per the configuration above), but they are not selected.
I attach 2 pictures below, for better explanation

However, when I try to configure the Pivot-Table, I get the famous error:
"unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class"

The instructions I use (right below the other shown above are):
the error apperas in the first line after the "With" statement (PivotFields).

Thanks

Table

[image: 1]

Pivot-Table

[image: 2]

I tried different versions of the VBA instructions, but the one shown are the ones I really think should be right, but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

- Add `.Value` to fix the issue ( Tested on M365 )
- The caption ( the 2nd argument of `AddDataField`) of data field can't be same as the field name.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [PivotTable.AddDataField method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.adddatafield?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm235142)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
With PivotSIC
   .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 3).Value).Orientation = xlRowField
   .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 2).Value).Orientation = xlRowField
   .AddDataField .PivotFields(WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value), "Sum of " & WSAP.Cells(1, 4).Value, xlSum
End With
```

Comment: That actually worked well.
However it created another error at the pivot creation:
run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error
    Set PivotSIC = PivotSICCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WSAP.Cells(1, 10), TableName:="SIC Code Pivot")

Comment: Do you have other pivottable named `SIC Code Pivot`?

Comment: No, I created and named only 1.

Comment: Pleaes edit the post to share all code.